# dependency error in standalone build.gradle

Tags: build.gradle

I am trying to hit a remote script thru ssh using gradle...but I am getting certain error.

Below is the build file:

```
    buildscript{
    repositories {      
        maven {
            println('Hello World')
            url "https://adlm.nielsen.com/artifactory/plugins-release/"
            credentials {
                username '********'
                password '********'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
            classpath group: 'org.hidetake', name: 'gradle-ssh-plugin', version: '2.7.0'
        }
}       

remotes {
      web01 {
    role 'webServers'
    host = '********hetibd043.********'
    user = '********'
    password = '********'
  }
}

task reload << {
  ssh.run {
    session(remotes.role('webServers')) {
      execute 'pwd'
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bi'.
> Could not find method remotes() for arguments     [build_dors3zgr32fbn8jukg7pqp34n$_run_closure1@70606922] on root project 'bi' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Please help resolving this...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the plugin isn't applied. Therefore the method can't be found.

```
    apply plugin: "org.hidetake.ssh"
```